# XML File not found when transform

Tags: java, xml, dom

I was trying to modify an xml file by using DOM and this happened:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\myproject\build\web\xml\myFile.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:263)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:296)
        at utils.UpdateUtils.BookUpdate(UpdateUtils.java:36)
```

This is my code

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = db.parse(f);
        searchAndModify(doc); //modify xml's contents

        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
        Result result = new StreamResult(f);
        TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tff.newTransformer();
        trans.transform(source, result);
```

f is my xml, generated. It parsed to Document doc just fine. However, when transformed, exception was thrown.

I've tried to parse to a new xml, same folder, but to no avail:

```
Result result = new StreamResult(new File(path, "newFile.xml"));

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\myProject\build\web\newFile.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Anyone has encountered this problem or has a solution for it? Please help me!

Comment: See this link for correct answer here ...
[Correct Answer for XML parsing ][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432145/xml-transform-results-in-filenotfoundexception

Answer (score 3):

`StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath).getAbsolutePath());`

Is working for the `file not found exception`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem is here:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\myProject\build\web\newFile.xml
```

It looks to me like your file name starts with the six characters `file:\`.
Make sure your file name starts with `D:`.

If you happen to prefer using a URL over using a file name, be aware that
the above is not a valid URL, because URLs are required to use forward
slashes (`/`) on all platforms.

Comment: Actually the url is fine. Browser recognizes url that way.

Comment: It is not clear from your code what the type of `f` is, but since you are getting a `FileNotFoundException`, I'm guessing it is a `File` object.  A `File` object should not contain `"file:"` in it.

If `f` is a URL, then I would advise using the forward slashes.  Browsers are known for being highly fault-tolerant, and the `java.net.URL` class is also pretty fault-tolerant, but converting that URL to a `File` may very well cause a `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide correct file path for your xml file. seems you are trying to access a file in your web application, so you can specify your application resource path in web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>xmlPath</param-name>
  <param-value>D:\somefolder\</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then use

```
String xmlFilePath = new File(e.getServletContext().getInitParameter("xmlPath"));
File customerDataFile = new File(xmlFilePath , "newFile.xml");
```

Comment: print customerDataFile.getAbsolutePath() and check this what u r getting

Comment: if error due to \ try <param-value>D:/somefolder/</param-value>

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue and I believe I know what it is.

For me I had:

```
  // Make a string stream out of the xml.
  Source source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
  FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stream);
  transformer.transform(source, result);
  stream.close();
```

which worked fine

I then polished this with

```
  // Make a string stream out of the xml.
  Source source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
  // Transform it straight into the output file.
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
  transformer.transform(source, result);
```

which also worked fine on my development machine.

Unfortunately it then broke when I installed this on site. It transpired that the version of `xalan` on site was older than my test setup. It appears that older versions of `xalan` had problems writing directly to `File`s.

It seems @VGR's [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13545618/823393) was close.

The subtle point to notice is the *file:\D:\...* should actually read *file:/D:/...* which is the problem with earlier versions of xalan.

Comment: I see a [fix](http://marc.info/?l=xalan-cvs&m=98893081521937) that looks like it is intended to fix this issue.