# XML Transform results in FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, xml, xslt, solaris

The earlier question I posted is closed because of lack of information.
 Please let me know if I am missing something here. The transformer seems to be adding file:/ to the beginning of my file path.

I am working in a Solaris environment, and here is what happens when the transform gets applied:

```
DOMSource sourcexml = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult resultxml = new StreamResult(new File("file.xml"));
transformer.transform(sourcexml, resultxml);
```

The exception I get is:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/opt/origenate/or_dev87/apps/documentarchive/file.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Note, the file exists in /opt/origenate/or_dev87/apps/documentarchive/file.xml, but the transformer object is looking for file:/opt/origenate/or_dev87/apps/documentarchive/file.xml.

Why does it append the file:/? Is there anyway I can remove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to execute below code:

```
DOMSource sourcexml = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult resultxml = new StreamResult(new File("file.xml").getAbsolutePath());
transformer.transform(sourcexml, resultxml);
```